# Java Assign a Value to an array cell

Tags: java, arrays, cell

I have the class Mappa and subclass MappaFermi with the array attribute Sector sector, each of the cells of the array is supposed to have a name, in the code of the class constructor i haven't had any problem naming them (all tests were successfull), however in the subclass constructor i get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 14 when trying to run a NotNull assertion. I set the array as protected so i can use it in the subclass.

```
public class Mappa {
    private Name mappaName;
    protected Sector [][] sector;
    private int Matrix [][];
    private static final int X=23;
    private static final int Y=14;
    public Mappa (Name mappaName){
        this.mappaName=mappaName;
        sector = new Settore[X][Y];
        for (int i=0; i < X; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<Y; j++) {
                sector[i][j] = new Settore (i,j);
            }
        }
        Matrix = new int[23][14];
        if(mappaName==Name.FERMI){
            sector[10][8]=new Alieni(10,8);
            sector[10][9]=new Umani(10,9);
        }
        if(mappaName==Name.GALILEI||mappaName==Name.GALVANI){
            sector[10][5]=new Alieni(10,5);//i have run all tests and it was successful
            sector[10][7]=new Umani(10,7);
        }
    }
}
public class MappaFermi extends Mappa {
    public MappaFermi() {
        super(null);
        new Mappa(Name.FERMI);
        setMatrix(new int[][]{
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,2,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,1,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,1,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,1,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}});
        for (int i=0; i < 14; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<23; j++){
                if (getMatrix()[i][j]==1){
                    sector[i][j]=new Sicuro(i,j);//this is where i get the error, if i only write `new Sicuro(i,j);` it runs successfully but i'm not storing the value in the cell of the array
                }
                else {
                    if (getMatrix()[i][j]==2){
                        sector[i][j]=new Pericoloso(i,j);   
                    }
                    else {
                        if (getMatrix()[i][j]==3){
                            sector[i][j]=new Scialuppa(i,j);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }


    }
public class MappaFermiTest {

    @Test
    public void testMappaFermi() {
        Mappa mappa = new MappaFermi();
        assertNotNull(mappa);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sector has dimensions `[23][14]` but you're trying to initialize it with an iteration ``` [i in (0..14)]``[j in (0..23)] ```. You should either initialize it like this: `sector = new Settore[Y][X];` or inverse X and Y values.

Comment: thanks, i inversed the values so it worked. Can i ask you something? when i wrote new Mappa(Name.FERMI); inside of MappaFermi() it isn't supposed to set mappaName as Name.FERMI? because when i write a test to get mappaName it returns null, the same with sector[8][10]=new Alieni(8,10) it returns null instead of Alieni

Answer (score 0):

Reverse below loop statement

```
for (int i=0; i < 14; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<23; j++){
```

with

```
for (int i=0; i < 23; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<14; j++){
```

Since the dimension of Array sector is `[23][14];` i.e `23 Rows and 14 Columns` . So that is why you need to traverse the all rows and their columns respectively